# How to access private member - array with friend function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, friend

I am new to C++ and I write code to see how friend functions work. Here are two classes and I ask the user in friend function for parameters, which if they are equal with the values of the member variables,  to be displayed. And I can't access one of the private members - the array with the country names. In the function `int elcountry(element &e, supply s)` I am trying to display the number of elements which are of a certain type and from a particular country. The error is that member `supply::country, (s.country[i])` in  elCountry function is inaccessible. I don't know how to use `getCountry()` function to access the private array.

```
class element {
        friend class supply;
    private:
        string name;
        double value;
        int serial;
    public:
        element();
        int elCountry(element &e, supply &s);
         double* nominals(element &e, supply &s);
        string getName() {
            return name;
        }
        int getSerial() {
            return serial;
        }
    };
    class supply {
    private:
        int serial;
        string country[5];
        int n;
    public:
        supply();
        string* getCountry() {
            string country = new string[5];
                return country;
        }
        friend int elCountry(element &e, supply &s);
        friend double* nominals(element &e, supply &s);
    };
    int elcountry(element &e, supply s){
        string names, Country;
        int n;
        cout << "enter country = "; cin >> Country;
        cout << "enter name of the element = "; cin >> names;
        cout << "enter number of elements = "; cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (Country == s.country[i] && names  == e.getName() && n ==  e.getSerial()) {
                cout << "the country is " << count << endl;
                cout << "the name is" << names << endl;
                cout << "the number is " << n << endl;
            }
        }
           return n;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure your `getCountry()` does not do what you want (i.e. it has nothing to do with the `string country[5]`, but always creates and returns a newly allocated array).

Comment: It doesn't even compile!  `country` needs to be `string*`, not `string`.

Comment: Avoid using `new`.  This code is full of memory leaks.  Use `std::vector` instead (then you don't have to worry about length issues).  Although, thinking about it, do you think "string[5]" declares a string (upto) five characters long?  It doesn't.  It declares five empty strings, each of which can be of unlimited length.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of two functions don't match, they're irrelevant, it's not `friend` function at all.

```
friend int elCountry(element &e, supply &s);
             ~                          ~
int elcountry(element &e, supply s){
      ~
```

Note that the names don't match either.

Comment: Also note that the names don't match (capital 'C' in one, little 'c' in the other).

Comment: @MartinBonner Thanks, added.